# Can you help me connect the dots?

Tags: riddle, wordplay, rhyme

> I come from a family of many.
>   But their names, I hardly remember any!
>   That's right, most names I partially forgot.
>   From this riddle, help me connect the dots.
>
> 1. Some tasty fruits of the color red.
> 2. Shaped as if he's made of bread.
> 3. Her colors are black, red, and yellow.
> 4. She might do her thing alongside a cello.
> 5. Goes by a nickname of letters three.
> 6. So pure, he might be in the Holy See.
> 7. A place many people come to read.
> 8. An animal we really don't need.
> 9. An instrument I think is really neat.
> 10. Something you might get when you trick-or-treat.
> 11. A wonderful place for a fish.
> 12. Something you do daily, I wish.

Tell me, what family do I come from, and what are their names?

Comment: Viola, Violet? Alongside a cello!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is:

> The signs of the zodiac, presented in order starting at Aries.

I'm missing explanations for a few, but here's what I've identified so far.

Some tasty fruits of the color red.

> ARIES, sounds like **cherries**; *previously berries, before Riley hinted at a better answer*

Shaped as if he's made of bread.

> TAURUS, sounds like 'torus', shape of a bagel or donut

Her colors are black, red, and yellow.

> GEMINI, sounds like Germany (black/red/yellow tricolour flag)

She might do her thing alongside a cello.

> CANCER, sounds like dancer

Goes by a nickname of letters three.

> LEO, the shortest sign at three letters long

So pure, he might be in the Holy See.

> VIRGO, the virgin pure

A place many people come to read.

> LIBRA, and library

An animal we really don't need.

> SCORPIO, and some anti-scorpion propaganda :P

An instrument I think is really neat.

> SAGITTARIUS, sounds like Stradivarius; *credit to F1Krazy*

Something you might get when you trick-or-treat.

> CAPRICORN, sounds like candy corn

A wonderful place for a fish.

> AQUARIUS, sounds like aquarium

Something you do daily, I wish

> PISCES, sounds like pisses; *credit to IanMacDonald*

EDIT: Title explanation

> The zodiacs are also constellations, made by connecting the dots/stars in the night sky.

Comment: Nice, you got the correct answer. But I'd like all of the names to be explained.

Comment: Added a few more. I'm uncertain about #4, and I still haven't got #12. Do the others look right?

Comment: They all look correct, but I had a better idea for #1 and #9.

Comment: Now #1 is correctly explained

Comment: Is #9 more related to an instrument like a ROT13(http://decode.org/?q=fvgne) or ROT13(http://decode.org/?q=nepure%27f+obj)?

Comment: #9 has a more satisfying explanation. You'll know it if you get it.

Comment: #9 might be ROT13(http://decode.org/?q=fgenqvinevhf).

Comment: @F1Krazy ah yes, that's definitely it; much more satisfying than my previous attempts. Edited to include your answer

Comment: Good job, now #9 Is correct. Now we just need #12.

Comment: #12 is obvious is you mispronounce it with "SS" instead of "SC"; even if it is crude.

Comment: @IanMacDonald That's it! I will accept the answer once this is added.

Comment: May I know how did you come up with this? Do you try to find the answer of many puzzles frequently so you have a lot of experience? Or are you gifted(: ? I'm really curious because I tried to solve this and it never came to my mind the answer: signs of the zodiac.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up at the same conclusion as ManyPinkHats, but with some different details, especially as concerns the order. Some of these make far more sense without them being correctly numbered. The strongest connection to point out is the three colors of corn.

> Some tasty fruits of the color red. - Gemini (pairs/pears)
>  Shaped as if he's made of bread. - Pisces (Pie)
>  Her colors are black, red, and yellow. - Capricorn (corn)
>  She might do her thing alongside a cello. - Taurus (no clue, but it was the only one left)
>  Goes by a nickname of letters three. - Leo
>  So pure, he might be in the Holy See. - Virgo (virgin)
>  A place many people come to read. - Libra (library)
>  An animal we really don't need. - Scorpio (scorpion)
>  An instrument I think is really neat. - Sagittarius (guitar)
>  Something you might get when you trick-or-treat. - Cancer (candy)
>  A wonderful place for a fish. - Aquarius (aquarium)
>  Something you do daily, I wish. - Aries (arise?)

Answer (score 1):

Partial stupid answer: your family is

> The words beginning with a B

Because

> Some tasty fruits of the color red. **Berries**
>  Shaped as if he's made of bread. **Baguette**
>  Her colors are black, red, and yellow. **Belgium**
>  She might do her thing alongside a cello. **bass**
>  Goes by a nickname of letters three. **Bob**
>  So pure, he might be in the Holy See. **?**
>  A place many people come to read. **Bed**
>  An animal we really don't need. **Bat?**
>  An instrument I think is really neat. **Banjo**
>  Something you might get when you trick-or-treat. **Brownies**
>  A wonderful place for a fish. **a box?**
>  Something you do daily, I wish. **Barbecue**

Comment: Interesting idea, but sadly incorrect. I suppose under your logic #6 could be bishop. I find the last three names particularly far fetched.

Comment: I know :) that wasn't really a serious answer

Comment: You're an irresponsible pet owner. Surely there's [a better place](https://www.walmart.com/ip/Hawkeye-0-5-Gallon-Fish-Bowl-Drum-Shaped-Shatterproof-Plastic-6-3-L-x-4-2-W-x-6-3-H/34334234) to keep a fish? :P

Comment: @Laurel a plastic **box** with water :)